# Remove other domains with Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So i have a preg_replace that replace all the links in a string with "[link removed]" :

```
/((https?:\/\/)?(\w+\.)+[a-z|A-Z]{2,}(:\d+)?((\/\w+)+(\.\w+)?)?\/?)/

Simplified:
http/https, subdomain, domain, tld, port, folder/file, extension, "/"
```

But i need to filter in a way that if the domain is "example.com" nothing is replaced like :

```
"http://notmydomain.com" -> "[link removed]"
"example.com" -> "example.com"
```

Comment: what if url is `http://example.abc.com` and `http://notmydomain.example.com` ? then what output?

Comment: @A-2-A Oh you're right, then let's just go with "example.com" only

Comment: You could call a function for the replace (I think that's `/e` or something) and have the function decide whether to replace or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/((https?:\/\/)?(?![^:\/\s]*\bexample\.com)(\b\w+\.)+[a-z|A-Z]{2,}(:\d+)?((\/\w+)+(\.\w+)?)?\/?)/
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?!            # Assert that it's impossible to match this from the current location:
 [^:\/\s]*     # Any number of characters except colon, slash or whitespace
 \b            # followed by a start-of-word anchor
 example\.com  # followed by example.com.
)              # End of lookahead.
```

Also, I've added another [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) before the `\w+` part to ensure that we don't match `xample.com` when given `example.com` as input.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mQ4eQ9/1).

Comment: As you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/oY7hH5/1) it match also files like foo.php

Comment: Yes, so does your regex.